# Getting a multiline yank to paste below the cursor

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

I'm trying to paste in Vim like so:

```
    a_1 "Day"
    a_2 "Week"
    a_neg_1 "Refused"
    a_neg_2 "Don’t know"
```

where I copy the last two lines and past them above the first two. Like this:

```
    a_neg_1 "Refused"
    a_neg_2 "Don’t know"
    a_1 "Day"
    a_2 "Week"
```

It seems like everytime I do a multiline yank, it always wants to paste it inline. like this:

```
    aa_neg_1 "Refused"
    a_neg_2 "Don’t know"_1 "Day"
    a_2 "Week"
```

Comment: how did you yank? with `v` or `ctrl+v` or `shift+v` or how? with `2yy` or `yj` (two lines) or `shift+v` it should work.

Comment: You may want to try to paste with upper case 'P'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy+Paste (or Cut+Paste) operations (in Vim terms: yank or delete and put) are mediated by registers. Registers can hold character-wise or line-wise text<sup>*</sup> (see `:help characterwise`).

- If you select “by characters” (`y5l`, `y2W`, `y$`, `v`<motion>`y`, et cetera), the register will end up with **character-wise** text.
- If you select “by lines” (`y2j`, `y}`, `V`<motion>`y`, et cetera), the register will hold **line-wise** text.

When you put the contents of a register, the placement of the text depends on whether it is character-wise or line-wise.

- When you put **character-wise** text, it will be inserted **immediately after/before the location of the cursor**.
- When you put **line-wise** text, it will be inserted **after/before the line the cursor is in**.

Whether the text is placed after or before the location of the cursor (line it is in) is controlled by which put command you use:

- `p` (lowercase) puts the text **after** the cursor (or after its line, if the register is currently line-wise)
- `P` (uppercase) puts the text **before** the cursor (or before its line, if the register is currently line-wise)

In short, how you yank/delete **and** how you put **both** affect the end result.

---

Based on your description, it seems like you are using `p` to put character-wise text (probably via `v`, or a single-click, mouse-based selection).

Instead, you should use `P` (put before) with line-wise text. If you are doing keyboard-based selection, use `V` (uppercase) instead of `v` (lowercase). If you are doing mouse-based selection, do a triple-click instead of a single click when starting your selection. Then, yank or delete and use `P` to do the final “paste” once you have moved up to the first line.

---

<sup>*</sup> Registers can also hold block-wise data (e.g. from the <kbd>Control-V</kbd> blockwise visual mode); when put, it will be placed in a block-wise fashion.

Comment: Can't begin to tell you what an awesome, thorough answer this is. The line-wise or character-wise distinction is not one I had heard of, and I can see where it's implications are huge. Thanks  for the insight. (I was able to derive from this my solution, which was simply 2dd and p)

Answer (score 2):

Lowercase <kbd>p</kbd> pastes after the cursor.

Uppercase <kbd>P</kbd> pastes before the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

In visual mode, <kbd>y</kbd> yanks sets of characters and <kbd>Y</kbd> yanks sets of lines.

When you yank characters, the following put is character-sensitive, which is causing your problem. Yank whole lines instead with <kbd>Y</kbd> and you should get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use simply `put` in ex mode:

```
:put
```